# How to bind an ObservableObject?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an ObservableObject like this on the main view.

```
class GlobalVariables: ObservableObject {
  @Published var showContactForm:Bool? = false
}
```

and I have a modal sheet on the main view that is shown like this

```
.sheet(isPresented: XXXXX, onDismiss: {


}) {
  ContactForm()
}
```

`XXXXX` would normally be something like `$showContactForm` but `showContactForm` is a published object inside `GlobalVariables`.

How do I bind that? What do I put on `XXXXX`?

Comment: You would have a property, e.g. `@StateObject var gv = GlobalVariables()`, then you'd do `$gv.showContactForm` (though I think it needs to be non-optional `Bool` for `isPresented`). It can also be `@ObservedObject` or `@EnvironmentObject` if instantiated outside the view

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Please make this commend an answer, so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bind to properties of an observable object, you'd create a property in the view that will hold an instance of the object and bind to it just like you would with any local `@State` or `@Binding` property:

```
struct SomeView: View {
  @StateObject var gv = GlobalVariables()

  var body: some View {
     // ...
     .sheet(isPresented: $gv.someCondition) {
        // ...
     }
  }
}
```

<sup>(Bear in mind that `isPresented:` expects a `Binding<Bool>`, so `someCondition` has to be a non-optional `Bool`)</sup>

- Use `@StateObject` if `GlobalVariables` was instantiated and owned by the view
- Use `@ObservedObject` - if it's instantiated outside the view and an instance is passed via `init`
- Use `@EnvironmentObject` - same as `@ObservedObject`, but instance is passed via `.environmentObject`